# Aerlink Wear Connect for iOS is not installing on Sony smartwatch 2

Tags: sony-smartwatch

I bought Sony Smartwatch 2 and successfully paired it with Moto X Play using Sony "SmartConnect" and installed applications like Gmail, etc...

Now I'm trying to pair it with my IPhone 5s. For that I need to install "Aerlink Wear Connect for iOS" application. But when I try to install this application it is installing in my Moto X mobile but not in SmartWatch.

How to install "Aerlink Wear Connect for iOS" application in my Smart Watch 2?

Comment: I read some of the reviews, and one of them mentioned that it didn't work with Sony Smartwatch 3 with the same reason as yours: couldn't install to watch. I'm afraid the app currently doesn't support Sony Smartwatch, and there's nothing we can't do other than waiting/telling their devs to support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that Sony Smartwatch 2 is not an Android Wear.

It is Sony own OS which made for Android. So that it is able to install application only developed by "Sony", but not installing all the available applications of Android Wear.

Sony Smartwatch 3 is Android Wear.